# What species of butterfly is this? Picture taken on 9-18-2018, near Helena, Mt

Tags: entomology, species

[image]

Butterfly picture taken on the 18th of September 2018 at an elevation of 1800 meters (6,000 feet) near Mount Helena in Montana, USA.

Comment: To me it looks like one of the tortoiseshell butterflies (genera _Aglais_ and _Nymphaiis_) - but I could not tell which one :/

Comment: Oh, and just to be certain: I guess "Helena, Mt" is "Helena, Montana, USA"? It might not be obvious to everyone in this international community :)

Comment: Yes, Helena, Montana, USA.

Answer (score 1):

That is a California Tortoiseshell google[https://www.butterfliesandmoths.org/species/Nymphalis-californica]